# CDK split API Gateway stack into 2 small stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a CDK stack in order to create API Gateway. Everything working as excepted if I create the stack in "small pieces" (comment part of the resources), But when I'm trying to create the completed stack I'm getting this exception:

```
 Number of resources, 224, is greater than maximum allowed, 200
```

Therefore, I tried to split my big stack into 2 smaller stacks, One stack creates the resource and creates half of the resources and the other one fills relevant data.

Code snippet:

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'ApiGWEndPoint', {
  restApiName: 'API_NAME,
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: 'STAGE_NAME',
  },
  description: "MyDescription",
  endpointTypes: [apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL]
});
```

I tried to create `cross-stack` or `nested-stack` and pass the API data into it, but no luck so far.

My goal is to create one stack which will contain 2 small stacks- both of them will point to the same API.
Or, if it is possible, create a workaround for the resource limit.

Any help will be much appreciated.

---

**Update 1.10.2020:**

Currently, there is no workaround for this issue, Ended up splitting the API Gateway Into many API Gateways.

**Update 10.24.2020:**

AWS CloudFormation now supports increased limits on five service quotas - template size, resources, parameters, mappings, and outputs. The maximum size of a template that can be passed in an S3 Object is now 1MB (previously 450KB). **The new per template limits for the maximum number of resources is 500 (previously 200)**.

More info can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how we are doing it right now. We basically have multiple stack that share the same API Gateway class (RestApi)

```js
class MultipleStackConstruct extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    // Main stack with shared components
    const commonStack = new CommonStack(
      scope,
      `common-stack`
    );

    // Module 1
    const moduleOneStack = new ModulOneStack(
      scope,
      `module-one`,
      {
        apiGatewayRestApi: commonStack.apiGatewayRestApi
      }
    );

    // Module 2, 3, etc.....
  }
}
```

This interface is used to pass the props to module stack:

```js
export interface CommonProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  apiGatewayRestApi: apigw.RestApi;
}
```

The common module will create the API Gateway object:

```js
export class CommonStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly apiGatewayRestApi: apigw.RestApi;

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: CommonProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    /******** SETUP API ********/
    this.apiGatewayRestApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, "MyAPI", {
      // Options here
    });
}
```

So the module stack itself will be something like this:

```js
export class ModuleOneStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: CommonProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    if (props && props.apiGatewayRestApi) {
      const apiGatewayRestApi = props.apiGatewayRestApi;

      // associate lambda with api gateway
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, we are using only one API Gateway with multiple Lambdas that are divided into multiple stack, because we've also encountered the limit problem.

There is a documentation from AWS that is doing the same thing using VPC:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#sharing-vpcs-between-stacks

Copy paste from my comment here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1477#issuecomment-568652807

Comment: This is working, but I still face the 200 limit.. as much as I can tell, this is currently unavailable to workaround.

Comment: True. As mentioned in @kylevoyto answer, you'll still can only do about 48 endpoints in the API Gateway stack...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve your goal by separating resources into smaller stacks. It doesn't seem like you need cross stack references or nested stacks.

Here is an example (in Python) with 295 resources split between two stacks.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from lambda_api.lambda_api_stack import APIStack
from lambda_api.lambda_api_stack import LambdasStack


app = core.App()
lambdas_stack = LambdasStack(app, 'lambdasstack')
APIStack(app, 'apistack', lambdas=lambdas_stack.lambdas)


app.synth()
```

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_apigateway as apigateway,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    core
)


class LambdasStack(core.Stack):

    @property
    def lambdas(self):
        return self._lambdas

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self._lambdas = list()
        for i in range(48):
            handler = _lambda.Function(
                self, f'Handler_{i}',
                function_name=f'Handler_{i}',
                runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
                code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('resources'),
                handler='handler.main'
            )
            self._lambdas.append(handler)


class APIStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, lambdas: list,
            **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        api = apigateway.RestApi(
            self, 'lambdas-api',
            rest_api_name='Lambdas Service',
            description='This service serves lambdas.'
        )

        for i in range(len(lambdas)):
            get_lambda_integration = apigateway.LambdaIntegration(
                lambdas[i],
                request_templates={
                    'application/json':
                    '{ "statusCode": "200" }'
                }
            )
            model = api.root.add_resource(f'Resource_{i}')
            model.add_method('GET', get_lambda_integration)
```

For this example, the API resource + Lambda integrations generate the most resources. Here is an outline of the resources created.

97 resources are created in `lambdasstack`.

- 1 `AWS::CDK::Metadata`
- 48 x 2 resources

  - 1 `AWS::Lambda::Function`
  - 1 `AWS::IAM::Role`

198 resources are created in `apistack`.

- 1 `AWS::CDK::Metadata`
- 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::Account`
- 1 `AWS::IAM::Role`
- 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`
- 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`
- 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage`
- 48 x 4 resources

  - 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource`
  - 1 `AWS::ApiGateway::Method`
  - 2 `AWS::IAM::Role`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the data using properties.

This requires to define public properties on the stack that provides output variables, and create an interface that extends `StackProperties` with the required properties to pass in.

The result may look like this:

```
const domain = new DomainStack(app, 'domain', {
  env: env,
  domainName: domainName,
  hostedZoneId: hostedZoneId
});

new WebsiteStack(app, 'website', {
  env: env,
  domainName: domainName,
  certificate: domain.certificate,
  hostedZone: domain.hostedZone,
});
```

Comment: Do you have any extended sample? I don't really get it

Comment: Do you try to split the stack into two stacks, or do you try to keep one stack and work around the limit using netsed stacks?

Comment: I try to keep one stack and workaround the limit using nested stacks which after long research leads me to try split the big stack into 2 small stacks. I'm open to try anything that could fix my issue. what do you recommend?

Comment: Oh okay, I have misunderstood that, I would suggest you actually split the stack into multiple stacks if that is possible in your use case. If not - sorry for any inconvenience.

You can combine the stacks by passing required parameters or components to other stacks using plain typescript properties, deployment can than be done using wildcards -> `cdk deploy 'api*'`

Comment: I've tried to do that and split into small stacks but I'm still getting the resource limit. My guess is the apigateway.RestApi resource is the issue.