# aws ressource limit api - how to separate stacks on RestApi

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

as i am using aws-cdk to define aws stacks, i am running into some limits here and i have no idea how to solve it.

First of all, there is a non-changeable limit on resources of 200 per stack.
this means, each stack that is used in cloudformation is limited to 200.

For a long time this was not an issue, since it was easy to create a stack which holds multiple different stacks of different usage ( S3, ApiGateway, IoT etc. )

Now i am running into the issue, that the APIGatewayStack ( for a RestApi ) is exceeding the limit of 200 Ressources and i can not deploy anymore.

I already seperated the lambdas from api- endpoints, so i do not have any potential to gain some ressources here.

My Idea was to create an CfnOutput for either the RestApi or its root Resourse, so i could create either a Restapi Object with

Approach #1 - create RestApi from RestApiId

Stack#1

```
const outputGm = new CfnOutput(this, 'RestApiGatewayId', {
         description: 'RestApiGatewayId',
         value: api.restApiId,
         // This Name must be unique
         exportName: 'RestApiGatewayId',
      });
```

Stack#2

```
const api = RestApi.fromRestApiId(this, 'rest-api-extension', 'RestApiGatewayId');
```

the issue here is, that api now is from type IRestApi which can not be used for further needed modifications like

```
const models = new ModelDefinitions.ModelDefinitions(api);
// Argument of type 'IRestApi' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RestApi'.
```

OR

```
const notifications = api.root.addResource('notifications');
// Property 'root' does not exist on type 'IRestApi'.
```

Approach #2 - create Output of root Resource

Unfortunatly, creating an RestApi with `fromRestApiId` does return an IRestApi Object, which is not containing all necessary properties to use it for a Resource creation:

```
const api = RestApi.fromRestApiId(this, 'rest-api-extension', 'RestApiGatewayId');
const resourceProps: ResourceProps = {
         parent: api,
         /* 
          * Type 'IRestApi' is missing the following properties from type 'IResource': restApi, resourceId, path, resourceForPath, and 5 more.
          */
         pathPart: 'root',
      };
const root = new Resource(apiGWStack, 'root-node', resourceProps);
// apiGWStack is the original stack which i am passing to the extension via:

const apiGatewayExtensionStack = new ApiGatewayExtensionStack(app, 'ApiGatewayExtensionStack', apiGWStack, { env: environment });
```

What am i missing here? I do not want to use a second ( or third in future ) seperate Rest-Api because it has a lot of endpoints.

Do you see any solution here on this? How do you handle Big Api Structures on AWS ?

Thanks for Help!

Comment: I've been stuck on this issue for days. I speak with aws cdk guys and since this limitation is cloud formation, you have nothing to do about it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393111/cdk-split-api-gateway-stack-into-2-small-stacks

Comment: i was trying the proposal from your link and it does not work due to some error.

So how did you manage to create an api with more than 200 resources?
multiple apis?

Comment: I couldn't, see my latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so aws is not increasing this Cloudformation ressource limit.
Also you can not do a nested Rest-Api Stack since there is no way to connect.

But i could not accept the fact that there is not any solution.
I remembered, that you can use ngx_http_proxy_module at nginx to serve content from from another server. So i checked if this is also working with an aws-gateway.

And even better, it can be used for multiple use-cases:

( Please note, that i removed all references to ssl-certificate in this conf )

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.tld.conf**

```
# server configuration
#
server {

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name yourdomain.tld;

    add_header "Allow" "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" always;

    #
    # Default Location will be mapped to proxy_set_header HOST  
    # API #1 - simple forwarding on aws-gateway

    location / {
        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;                  
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/;
        proxy_set_header Host "abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    }

    #
    # Location /admin and nested below will be mapped to proxy_set_header HOST  
    # API #2 - speficic slug forwarding on on aws-gateway

    location /admin {
        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;          
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://zyxwvutsrq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/;
        proxy_set_header Host "zyxwvutsrq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }

    #
    # Location /users and nested below will be mapped to proxy_set_header HOST  
    # API #3 - specific slug mapping to specific slug on aws-gateway

    location /users {
        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;          
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://ababababab.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/users;
        proxy_set_header Host "ababababab.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}

server {

    if ($host = yourdomain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name yourdomain.tld;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Before:

- https://abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
- https://zyxwvutsrq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
- https://ababababab.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/users

Now:

- https://yourdomain.tld
- https://yourdomain.tld/admin
- https://yourdomain.tld/users

It is a bit more work on maintainance if you have a

- development
- staging
- production server

since you might need to update all conf-files when there is new endpoints, but this way you also benefit from serving the REST-Api with a nice url

https://yourdomain.tld instead of those *https://ababababab.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/*

Comment: Can you share the whole solution? if I get you correctly you created nginx load balancer above the API Gateway and used it instead of the original API Gateway?

Comment: This is the whole solution. I just launched an ec2 instance with an elastic ip, pointed domain name via a-record to the ip. 
installed nginx on that server and created configuration like mentioned.

i did not use more aws ressources like loadbalancers etc.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for an answer, AWS now allows using Imported RestApis that can help us deploy resources to same API Gateway using multiple stacks.
Create the main RestApi in one stack:

```
mainApi = new apigateway.RestApi(...)
```

Then use this to create another RestApi (in another nested stack) that is imported from the main one:

```
importedApi = RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, 'RestApiScore', {
  restApiId: mainApi.restApiId,
  rootResourceId: mainApi.restApiRootResourceId
});
```

You can create as many IRestApis as you like. And adding resources to them will deploy the resources to the same Gateway even if you do it from multiple stacks.

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/commit/21a1de308101a5f7e07558ff8c786f27e5235289