# Error removing Lambda from API Gateway shared across stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have implemented [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59464034/6440140) to share one API GW RestAPI across multiple stacks in AWS CDK in TypeScript.

Basically I create one Rest API in a common stack and pass it to the other stacks where I add resources and lambda integrations. It works fine so far.

However, when I remove a lambda integration the deployment fails with this error: `Export users-stack:ExportsOutputFnGetAttusersstackauthorizeuserC81C1452ArnB7D2BE00 cannot be deleted as it is in use by common-stack`

My understanding of what's happening is that CDK/CloudFormation is trying to deploy the user-stack first which includes the deletion of the function referenced in the error message. The REST API in the common-stack still references this lambda at this point as it is not yet redeployed and CloudFormation is not "smart enough" to infer that the reference to the lambda function will be gone soon.

Is there any possibility to fix this? I looked into whether it is possible to programmatically clear the lambda integrations in the user-stack but it does not like it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is referenced in the common stack, so you cannot delete the stack from which it comes.

The solution here is to copy the value of your `ExportsOutputFnGetAttusersstackauthorizeuserC81C1452ArnB7D2BE00` (you can easily find it on Cloudformation console, in the outputs tab of your users-stack). Then you must hardcode it in your common stack where it is referenced and deploy your stacks with this change.

In this way, the common-stack will no longer use your output from users-stack.

After that, you should be able to remove your resource from users-stack and deploy it without any issues.